# При форматировании код сразу после списка не распознаётся

Tags: поддержка, правки, блок-кода

При редактировании (или создании) вопросов-ответов, код, вставленный сразу же после списка, не распознаётся как код.

Пример:

---

```
Это код (четыре пробела в начале строки).
```

1. Теперь список

   Это тоже код (четыре пробела в начале строки), но он не форматируется в виде кода.

Необходимо внести хотя бы одну строку «обычного» текста.

```
И только после этого код начинает распознаваться.
```

---

Вопрос: это «баг» или «фича»?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Это фича. Код может находиться как внутри элемента списка, так и за пределами списка. Текст в списке может разделяться на абзацы.

1. Чтобы расположить **код внутри элемента списка**, нужно добавить **отступ в 8 пробелов**.
2. Чтобы расположить **код вне списка сразу после списка**, можно воспользоваться **HTML комментарием**.

Пример:

```
Предложение 1.1.
Предложение 1.2.

Предложение 2.

    Код 1.1.
    Код 1.2.

1.  Предложение 3.1.

        Код 2.1.
        Код 2.2.

    Предложение 4.1.
    Предложение 4.2.

    Предложение 5.1.

2.  Предложение 6.1.
    Предложение 6.2.

    Предложение 7.1.

<!---->

    Код 3.1.
    Код 3.2.

Предложение 8.1.
```

Результат:

> Предложение 1.1.
>   Предложение 1.2.
>
> Предложение 2.
>
> ```
> Код 1.1.
> Код 1.2.
> ```
>
> 1. Предложение 3.1.
>
>    ```
>    Код 2.1.
>    Код 2.2.
>    ```
>
>    Предложение 4.1.
>      Предложение 4.2.
>
>    Предложение 5.1.
> 2. Предложение 6.1.
>      Предложение 6.2.
>
>    Предложение 7.1.
>
> ```
> Код 3.1.
> Код 3.2.
> ```
>
> Предложение 8.1.

Comment: С комментарием очень полезный хак.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще с Markdown дело обстоит так: чтобы определить, баг или фича, код нужно проверить на [Babelmark](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=%0A---%0A%20%20%20%20%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%28%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%29.%0A%0A1.%20%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%28%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%29%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0.%0A%0A%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%20%C2%AB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%C2%BB%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%D0%98%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F.). Если почти везде так — то фича, а если почти нигде — то баг.

[В данном случае](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=%0A---%0A%20%20%20%20%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%28%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%29.%0A%0A1.%20%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%28%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%29%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0.%0A%0A%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%20%C2%AB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%C2%BB%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%D0%98%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F.) везде текст с 4мя пробелами, располагающийся после строки списка, считается частью того же элемента списка.